# Configuring multiple UDP sockets on a single port

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp

I'm trying to implement a peer-to-peer chat application using UDP and I was wondering about how to scale the program to multiple users.

As I understand it, UDP needs only one socket to send and receive data using the `recvfrom` and `sendto` functions. Using the data from the address fields passed to these functions, I can determine which user I'm communicating with.

I was wondering if I could create multiple UDP sockets on the same port for each peer that I'm talking to. That way, if data comes from a peer X, then the data goes to the UDP port and gets passed to the appropriate socket that is 'bound' to X's address.

Is there anyway I could do this while still using UDP?

Comment: @close-voter(s) Come off it. Not knowing the answer != 'too broad'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can specify SO_REUSEADDR (SO_REUSEPORT on Linux) before binding the UDP socket (*all* sockets including the first), and then connect each socket to the appropriate target, but it's really not necessary. Just dispatch each message arriving on a single socket according to its source-address.

Comment: So using SO_REUSEPORT guarantees that datagrams from X will go to X's socket and datagrams from Y will go to Y's socket, which are both actually on the same port?

Comment: No, connecting the socket to X or Y does that. SO_REUSEPORT allows you to, err, reuse the port.

Comment: So I have to use `connect`...
Hmm...I kind of get what you're saying...
What I really wanted to do is take all of those sockets and put them into a nice select loop, so I can read from each peer when they're ready. I also feel like the select option would help with timeouts. 
Thoughts, Mr.EJP?

Comment: I've already commented. Don't do it. Use a single socket. You can use a read timeout with that. There's no advantage to using lots of sockets.

Comment: @ReiJinThunderKeg: yes, you can use a `select()` loop. `connect()` merely establishes a static relationship between the source and destination address/port pairs, which in turn enables use of `send()` and `recv()` on a UDP socket. You can `bind()` multiple UDP sockets to the same port, then `connect()` them to their respective peers, and then use `select()` to know when to call `recv()`. Of course, this is fairly redundant when a single UDP socket can receive packets from multiple peers, where `recvfrom()` tells you the peer of each packet read.

Comment: Having to deal with just one socket makes it a lot less messier, but I've been stumped as to how to deal with timeouts. This is partly because I cannot block at a `recvfrom` and hence cannot use `SO_RCVTIMEO` as an option. I was thinking maybe signal alarms, but interrupts are expensive...

Comment: Why can't you block? And if you can't, why can't you use `select()`?

Comment: @ReiJinThunderKeg if this was a threaded app this would be fairly easy: Have a receive thread constantly drain the single socket and put incoming packets in a queue (or a queue per client, whatever you want). You can then put a custom timeout policy on the queue(s). It doesn't make much sense to use a timeout on a UDP socket.

Comment: I''m practicing using multiplexing, so no threads. I can't block, because some other peer may send data and I can't keep them waiting while I block at the current peer. I intend to use select on my UDP socket and I was exploring options to configure timeouts and I came across `signalfd`, which seems to fit my needs.